# Bootstrap popover, strage underscore

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using the Bootstrap API. I have a font-awesome icon that spins when you hover over it, easy enough. Then I added the popover when you hover, so now the icon has a popover and spins when you hover your mouse over it. However, I am getting a strange underscore character to the right of the icon like this...[image]

It happens on every icon except the far right, there is no underscore, it works as intended.

Has anyone ever had this problem, where is it coming from?

HTML:

```
<a class="popover-icon" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Let us do the hard work for you.">
   <i class="hoverable fa fa-code fa-2x"></i>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
 <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"</script>

    <script>
    $(".hoverable").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('fa-spin');
    });

    $(".hoverable").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-spin');
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(".hover-dropdown-menu").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('dropdown-toggle');});
    </script>

    <script>
    $(function(){$(".popover-icon").popover();});
    </script>

    <!-- Custom JavaScript for the Side Menu and Smooth Scrolling -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: My guess without a working fiddle, is that you have  `selector: hover {text-decoration: underline;}` or `border-bottom` applied. You might check that.

Comment: I haven't found it to be one of those, you can highlight the underscore like it is a character if that helps.

Comment: If you make a fiddle, others can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Is there a way to include font-awesome files in a js-fiddle?

Comment: If they are hosted somewhere online yes - preferably your own server so it's not hotlinked.

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the problem in fiddle...

Comment: in chrome, hover the character -> right-click -> inspect element

Comment: I fixed it by taking the anchor tag out of the html, just using an <i> tag and adding the classes from the <a> tag to the <i> tag.

Comment: You could answer your own question and accept it - maybe helping other people with a similar problem in the future.